# Api Gateway S3 Proxy with Cloud Formation wont accept Bucket ARN but will accept all buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a simple Cloud Formation script that I am working with. It creates a host of resources including an API Gateway and S3 bucket, the former of which I want to server as a Proxy for the later when uploading objects. Here is the role definition:

```
BucketItemApiMethodRole:
Type: AWS::IAM::Role
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: Allow
        Principal:
          AWS: "*"
          Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com
        Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: "tc-bucketitemmethodrole"
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "s3:Put*"
            Resource: !GetAtt RawBucket.Arn
```

Here is the relevant portion from API Gateway Method that does the Put against S3:

```
Integration:
    Type: AWS
    Credentials: !GetAtt BucketItemApiMethodRole.Arn
    IntegrationHttpMethod: PUT
    PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
    RequestParameters:
      integration.request.header.Content-Disposition: method.request.header.Content-Disposition
      integration.request.header.Content-Type: method.request.header.Content-Type
      integration.request.path.key: method.request.path.item
    Uri:
      Fn::Join:
        - "/"
        - - "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:s3:path"
          - !Ref RawBucketName
          - "{key}"
    IntegrationResponses:
      - StatusCode: 201
```

My question is this: When I set the Resource for the Role to "*" it works fine. When I specify the Arn directory, as shown, I get an Access Denied error from S3. Looking for any thoughts as to what I might be running into.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Needed a BucketPolicy - that fixed it